# CircleCrop PHP not working

Tags: php, gd

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure out the problem with the following script: **`https://github.com/bebensiganteng/Simple-PHP-Circular-Image-Crop`** - it's basically a script that crops images and makes them circular. I have it working fine locally, but for some reason (which for the life in me I can't figure out) it doesn't work on my server using the full path to the image url.

**Using the script**

```
<img src="http://crownedtraders.com/circlecrop.php?path=http://crownedtraders.com/profile_pictures/395030_00f648aa3c2.jpg" width="74" height="73">
```

This should work (the image is there), but i have a feeling it's because I'm using a full path to the image.

For the life in me I can't get it to work, any help is really appreciated.

**Circlecrop.php**

```
<?php

    class CircleCrop
    {

        private $src_img;
        private $src_w;
        private $src_h;
        private $dst_img;
        private $dst_w;
        private $dst_h;

        public function __construct($img, $dstWidth, $dstHeight)
        {
            $this->src_img = $img;
            $this->src_w = imagesx($img);
            $this->src_h = imagesy($img);
            $this->dst_w = $dstWidth;
            $this->dst_h = $dstHeight;
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            if (is_resource($this->dst_img))
            {
                imagedestroy($this->dst_img);
            }
        }

        public function display()
        {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng($this->dst_img);
            return $this;
        }

        public function reset()
        {
            if (is_resource(($this->dst_img)))
            {
                imagedestroy($this->dst_img);
            }
            $this->dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($this->dst_w, $this->dst_h);
            imagecopy($this->dst_img, $this->src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->dst_w, $this->dst_h);
            return $this;
        }

        public function size($dstWidth, $dstHeight)
        {
            $this->dst_w = $dstWidth;
            $this->dst_h = $dstHeight;
            return $this->reset();
        }

        public function crop()
        {
            $this->reset();

            $mask = imagecreatetruecolor($this->dst_w, $this->dst_h);
            $maskTransparent = imagecolorallocate($mask, 255, 0, 255);
            imagecolortransparent($mask, $maskTransparent);
            imagefilledellipse($mask, $this->dst_w / 2, $this->dst_h / 2, $this->dst_w, $this->dst_h, $maskTransparent);

            imagecopymerge($this->dst_img, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->dst_w, $this->dst_h, 100);

            $dstTransparent = imagecolorallocate($this->dst_img, 255, 0, 255);
            imagefill($this->dst_img, 0, 0, $dstTransparent);
            imagefill($this->dst_img, $this->dst_w - 1, 0, $dstTransparent);
            imagefill($this->dst_img, 0, $this->dst_h - 1, $dstTransparent);
            imagefill($this->dst_img, $this->dst_w - 1, $this->dst_h - 1, $dstTransparent);
            imagecolortransparent($this->dst_img, $dstTransparent);

            return $this;
        }

    }

    if(isset($_GET['path'])) {

        $path = $_GET["path"];
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

        $width = imagesx($image);
        $height = imagesy($image);
        $crop = new CircleCrop($image,$width,$height);
        $crop->crop()->display();

    }

?>
```

**Error log**
http://pastebin.com/5ZNN11rG

Comment: Anything in your Apache logs? Sometimes, image processing will exceed the amount of memory you're allowed to use, and the request will fail. There might be helpful information in the error log file.

Comment: You can also [use CSS to make a circular image](http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/).

Comment: Totally forgot about checking the error log, here it is: http://pastebin.com/5ZNN11rG

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory to me: `http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[02-Jan-2014 15:41:21 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg() [<a href='function.imagecreatefromjpeg'>function.imagecreatefromjpeg</a>]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/wpvaultc/public_html/crownedtraders.com/circlecrop.php on line 69
```

Based on the first line (above) from the error log you posted, you may want to try adding this (if your host allows these sorts of changes):

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
```

This will override the `allow_url_fopen` setting, and presumably will allow `file_get_contents()` to work as you expect.

As a side note, I'd strongly suggest encoding the URL you're passing as a parameter. `http://something.com?param=http://somethingelse.com` is not a valid URL, but `http://something.com?param=http%3A%2F%2Fsomethingelse.com` is. In your code, you can use the built-in functions `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Is it possible to use this script in a different way without file_get_contents()? as it's disabled on my host.

Comment: If it is disabled on your host, let the users upload the image to your server and then manipulate the image without foreign url opening

Comment: Both resources are on your own host. Is that always going to be the case? If so, have you tried using a relative path?

Comment: Ah, yes... a relative path works. See here: http://crownedtraders.com/circlecrop.php?path=profile_pictures/395030_00f648aa3c2.jpg

Comment: I have it working, thanks a lot Thomas you were really helpful.